# Calculate dot product of array of nxn arrays with nx1 arrays

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

Given:

```
A = np.array([[[10, -1],
               [-1, 10]],
              [[30,  4],
               [5,  10]]])
B = np.array([[[5],[2]],
              [[3],[4]]])
```

I would like to take the dot product between the two arrays with the 2x2 arrays in A, with the 2x1 arrays in B, so what I would like to do is:

```
res = dot(A, B)
```

Such that the result is:

```
res = [[[48],[15]],[[106],[55]]]
```

Or perhaps easier:

```
res = [[48, 15], [106, 55]]
```

But I know that my array `A` is quite long such that `A.shape` is `mx2x2` and my array `B` always has a length equal, i.e. `B.shape` is `mx2x1`.`m` could be any value e.g. `250, 000`.

I have attempted `np.tensordot`, but could not work out how to correctly configure the axes to work to get the result I was after. How do I perform this dot product of nested arrays?

Comment: Can you explain how you get the values in your expected result? I assume `48` is `10 * 5 + (-1) * 2`, but where does `-25` come from?

Comment: My  apologies, I didn't do the calculation correctly, it was meant to be 15 `(-1 * 5 + 2*10)`

Comment: I think you probably just need `A @ B` (or `np.matmul(A, B)`) which is `[[[48], [15]], [[106], [55]]]`, but `74` and the other `-25` appear to be miscalculated too.

Comment: Thanks! That solved it correctly. Apologies again, yes that appeared to be wrong too

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
In [60]: A = np.array([[[10, -1], 
    ...:                [-1, 10]], 
    ...:               [[30,  4], 
    ...:                [5,  10]]]) 
    ...: B = np.array([[[5],[2]], 
    ...:               [[3],[4]]])                                              
In [61]: A                                                                      
Out[61]: 
array([[[10, -1],
        [-1, 10]],

       [[30,  4],
        [ 5, 10]]])
In [62]: A.shape                                                                
Out[62]: (2, 2, 2)
In [63]: B.shape                                                                
Out[63]: (2, 2, 1)
```

`matmul`, `@` is designed to do the `dot` on 'batches' like this:

```
In [64]: A@B                                                                    
Out[64]: 
array([[[ 48],
        [ 15]],

       [[106],
        [ 55]]])
```

`einsum` also works

```
In [65]: np.einsum('mij,mjl->mil',A,B)                                          
Out[65]: 
array([[[ 48],
        [ 15]],

       [[106],
        [ 55]]])
```

`np.dot` performs an outer product on the dimensions that aren't summed:

```
In [66]: np.dot(A,B).shape                                                      
Out[66]: (2, 2, 2, 1)
```

Your desired result can extracted from a diagonal, but this is slower, since it is, in effect throwing away half the results:

```
In [68]: np.dot(A,B)[range(2),:,range(2),:]                                     
Out[68]: 
array([[[ 48],
        [ 15]],

       [[106],
        [ 55]]])
```

Answer (score 0):

There are two ways to do matrix multiplication, with `numpy`:

1) Dot product of two arrays

```
np.dot(A,B)
```

output:

```
array([[[[ 48],
         [ 26]],

        [[ 15],
         [ 37]]],


       [[[158],
         [106]],

        [[ 45],
         [ 55]]]])
```

2) Element wise multiplication (Hadamard product):

```
np.multiply(A,B)
```

output:

```
array([[[50, -5],
        [-2, 20]],

       [[90, 12],
        [20, 40]]])
```

Comment: I understand that, but I am asking about arrays nested within an array, if you refer to my original question, I can clarify if need be.